Error with Identity Server and Client App
I'm following along with the steps described here:
https://hts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html
and getting the following error in the mvc client:
2024-07-05 14:38:57.607 -04:00 [DBG] Connection 0HN4T46RO7B2O established using the following protocol: "Tls13"
2024-07-05 14:38:57.698 -04:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:7234/Home/Privacy - null null
2024-07-05 14:38:57.707 -04:00 [DBG] The request path /Home/Privacy does not match a supported file type
2024-07-05 14:38:57.710 -04:00 [DBG] 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/Home/Privacy'
2024-07-05 14:38:57.712 -04:00 [DBG] Endpoint 'IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient)' with route pattern '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}' is valid for the request path '/Home/Privacy'
2024-07-05 14:38:57.714 -04:00 [DBG] Request matched endpoint 'IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient)'
2024-07-05 14:38:57.719 -04:00 [DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
2024-07-05 14:38:57.723 -04:00 [DBG] Policy authentication schemes  did not succeed
2024-07-05 14:38:57.726 -04:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2024-07-05 14:38:57.785 -04:00 [DBG] HandleChallenge with Location: https://localhost:44322/connect/authorize?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7234%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638558015377798439.ZWEzZGI1OWItNTAwYS00YzI2LTkwMGMtZGVjNzI0ZmM1MTZjNTQxYTdkMDQtMjg4Zi00N2U1LTg5ZDktOGU4ZmUwMjE5YTAy&state=CfDJ8N4mnYggvO1EmxOZVM5SE9PnyMYD11Fh4U7TKnjT6zG0N4Ingxs1bzwYt8ev5Mc2558w8Vc0y-QEAvQzFJbaVM9MrqzefXn91zrRzrBUVL-W-LdIsExT-dQ5X1N_4G7WCY3qQ6DsWdm9CchXs0sDTkgqTmWYulZcPvRCNgMn3-Y-sQYAsgSltRZlwkl9NNWt5oufVCvtcQP0yWHO_KeOvpHeebOU1Y-uP52yJrw2W15EXhx7T9K2MRuWcwRC9vZ_ymualA3coVHgNvI26iXcxzHPHVqx4tuXoLFKaq95HWALrh-JKWJfY_H7lc_sHIqM1A&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.1.2.0; and Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8N4mnYggvO1EmxOZVM5SE9PVkcRiW5LrFbFxUINAn7v-2W-58VReFRAG1fVOgE0tdjCqG8yro5Urkac4lSDaB2GqhoZoW8IlYgiqhKKGyfdgzE_HgAnlGPUAq2HO21rc8gKbJQEuRd9bcYrMFpqy0HK-O3B5E2XdRK6Iqyr4LnjDWRKjDWkeWwE9iyvMRGAi59rqPFP6J0wEjEml-kRAxQHAmWf3IXHBGBuNQz-YLcigMxvo3yvHsoPZDTPe_egwyYw3tG94WE76M1B8B0kC834=N; expires=Fri, 05 Jul 2024 18:53:57 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure; samesite=none; httponly,.AspNetCore.Correlation.XD3pXaL1E7xZ3-aW8OQQLsng-vgjcfDX3BolBIgFZ6E=N; expires=Fri, 05 Jul 2024 18:53:57 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure; samesite=none; httponly.
2024-07-05 14:38:57.787 -04:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
2024-07-05 14:38:57.789 -04:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:7234/Home/Privacy - 302 0 null 91.4072ms
2024-07-05 14:38:57.921 -04:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:7234/signin-oidc - application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1387
2024-07-05 14:38:57.926 -04:00 [DBG] POST requests are not supported
2024-07-05 14:38:57.929 -04:00 [DBG] 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/signin-oidc'
2024-07-05 14:38:57.931 -04:00 [DBG] Endpoint 'IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient.Controllers.HomeController.SignInCallBack (IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient)' with route pattern 'signin-oidc' is valid for the request path '/signin-oidc'
2024-07-05 14:38:57.933 -04:00 [DBG] Request matched endpoint 'IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient.Controllers.HomeController.SignInCallBack (IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient)'
2024-07-05 14:38:57.945 -04:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HN4T46RO7B2O", Request id "0HN4T46RO7B2O:00000003": started reading request body.
2024-07-05 14:38:57.946 -04:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HN4T46RO7B2O", Request id "0HN4T46RO7B2O:00000003": done reading request body.
2024-07-05 14:38:57.955 -04:00 [DBG] Updating configuration
2024-07-05 14:38:57.959 -04:00 [DBG] Received 'id_token'
2024-07-05 14:38:58.032 -04:00 [ERR] Exception occurred while processing message.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ValidateTokenUsingHandlerAsync(String idToken, AuthenticationProperties properties, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
2024-07-05 14:38:58.036 -04:00 [DBG] Exception of type 'SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException' thrown, Options.ConfigurationManager.RequestRefresh() called.
2024-07-05 14:38:58.039 -04:00 [INF] Error from RemoteAuthentication: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature..
2024-07-05 14:38:58.043 -04:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ValidateTokenUsingHandlerAsync(String idToken, AuthenticationProperties properties, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

Based on the guide, this should be working mostly out of the box. I've gotten through many errors due to latest version of dotnet though am getting stuck here. Clicking on the privacy tab should trigger redirect to identity server to login and then redirect back to privacy tab once login is successful. Can someone assist with this?
The identity server is in the IdentityServerQuickStart and the client is IdentityServerQuickStart.MvcClient: https://github.com/mperejda/IdentityServerQuickStart/tree/features/MEP/add-user-auth-with-open-id-connect

This error message was being caused by outdated packages. Bringing the following packages up to date resolved the issue

The two packages at 7.1.2 needed to be updated.
https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Support/issues/1197
